# Who receives email notifications about new comments?

Tags: blogger

I have added myself as an additional administrator to my wife's blog, so I can change all the settings, etc.

However, I am not getting emails about new comments posted by readers. Hence the questions:

- Who gets these notifications?
- How can I add myself to that list?

Answer (score 1):

In the Blogger dashboard, go to *Settings* → *Posts and Comments* and

1. turn comment moderation on (if it's not already); and
2. enter your email address in the **Email moderation requests to** field.

The email address already in the field is the one that any comment notifications are going to.

Comment: But then someone would need to accept the comments before they are published?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.   And it's a very good idea, unless you want the blog littered with comments like "This is very beautiful post" which link to spam sites off all varieties.

Answer (score 1):

In the Blogger dashboard, go to *Settings* → *Mobile and email*.

On that page, add your email address to the **Comment Notification Email** value.

(Turning on comment moderation isn't necessary to have this work.)